# Classes, Closures and Callables

Tags: php

I have written an abstract class which handles persisting an application's models. The code is generic and will work with any of the application's models. However, some models require some *specific processing* which is outside of the scope of the model's class or the functionality of the abstract class. The *specific processing* is the responsibility of the class extending the abstract class.

Therefore, I need the abstract class to be able to call a function defined in the extending class which will perform the *specific processing* required. Below is some example code which works. But I am not sure that it is the **right** way to do this (I have tried many different ways, but this is the only one I managed to get to work).

My questions are:

1. Is using `Closure` type correct in the parameter list for the `persistModel()` method?
2. Is the `Closure::fromCallable([$this, 'getPostFilename'])` the best (correct) way to pass the `getPostFilename()` method into the `persistModel()` method?

I realize that these questions are asking for some opinions, but I thought questions and the answers may be helpful to others who struggle with this as I am.

Working example code:

```
class Post
{
}

abstract class FacadeAbstract
{
    protected function persistModel(string $className, array $data, Closure $callabel = null)
    {
        $model = new $className();

        if (is_callable($callabel)) {
            echo $callabel($model);
        }
    }
}

class PostFacade extends FacadeAbstract
{
    public function createPost(array $data)
    {
        $this->persistModel(Post::class, $data, Closure::fromCallable([$this, 'getPostFilename']));
    }

    public function deletePost(array $data)
    {
        $this->persistModel(Post::class, $data);
    }

    private function getPostFilename(Post $model): string
    {
        return "the_file_name.json\n";
    }
}

class Controller
{
    public function actionGET(array $data)
    {
        $facade = new PostFacade();
        $facade->createPost($data);
    }
}

$controller = new Controller();
echo $controller->actionGET(['slug' => 'context/title']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to answer your questions:

In my opinion the [`callable`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php) type hint is more flexible. Of course this requires the usage of `call_user_func()` instead of just calling `$callabel()`:

```
function persistModel(callable $callabel = null)
{
    if ($callabel !== null) {
        call_user_func($callabel, $model);
    }
}
```

When using `callable` you no longer need `Closure::fromCallable()` and you can simply call

```
$this->persistModel([$this, 'getPostFilename']);
```

Note 1: When the call to `$callabel` is indeed the last action within `persistModel`, I would simply return the `$model` variable and call `getPostFilename` within `createPost`. But most likley your given code is exremely simplified and there is more than this.

Note 2: Have a look at the Strategy Design Pattern (Google will give plenty examples), *maybe* this will result in a neater solution.

Comment: I have tried your suggestion (this is one of the ways I tried previously), but get an error passing an array to the `$this->persistModel(Post::class, $data, [$this, 'getPostFilename']);` - **Argument 3 passed to FacadeAbstract::persistModel() must be callable or null, array given**

Comment: Your suggestion does work, **however**, the scope of the `getPostFilename()` method must be broadened to `protected`.